# Cannot install Joomla 3.6.5 because blank page appears

Tags: joomla, installation, screen, fedora

I tried to install Joomla 3.6.5,
but when I try to view `localhost.localdomain` to configure Joomla!, a blank page appears.

My specs:

- Apache version: 2.4.25
- PHP version: 2.6.0
- MySql version: 15.1
- Operating system: Fedora 26

Comment: Fedora 26 supports your joomla 3.6.5?

What steps did you take for your installation?

Does your lamp system work on Fedora? If not how did you install it?

Comment: At what step you get the blank page? Also, check console errors for the error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable PDO in Apache in web server.

Answer (score 0):

First Make Sure You have Read/Write Permissions for www folder and Joomla installation folder

Answer (score 0):

PHP Version 2.6.0? Are you really sure? Can you double check and post the real PHP version?

Your MySQL version is also wrong, could you please check? Something like 5.1 probably makes more sense. Note that 5.1 is the bare minimum to run a Joomla website, but it should work.

Also, can you modify your PHP settings (in `php.ini`) to display all errors? You can do that by ensuring that the following line is present in your `php.ini`:

```
display_errors =on
```